# Can creating a list in Lisp be called 'change of state'?

Tags: lisp

For the sake of argument can we say that when we create lists in Lisp, it is a change of state? Now that can be using cons, list or any other list creation functions.

Consider a filter function which filters odd number from list and keeps only even numbers. Now it does that by creating new lists and using recursion. Can we say there is change of state in the program? Assuming we already know interpreter's perspective.

Considering lists are objects and and when old objects are dropped in favour of new objects then it is change of state right?

Also how valid would it be to say that from technical point of view. I mean from Lisp interpreter perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all comes down to how you define "change of state", or better yet, the thing whose state we are talking about. States are properties of things, so to answer your question, we have to ask "the state of what exactly?"

Let's look at a couple of possible candidates:

In your filtering example, we have a list A. Filter constructs a new list B with only the even numbers.

The state of A is definitely not changed. That's the point of constructing a new list.

The state of B is definitely changed. Prior to the run of filter, it did not exist, now it does.

The state of the runtime environment also contains all the variables and as we added a new symbol with the filtered list, its state has certainly changed.

So, to answer your question: Yes. But keep in mind that state is a property of something and to really answer it correctly, you have to tell us whose state you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks it does answer my question. I wanted to know if there was **any** change of state in the program.